# How to write Previous,Current and Next row to an output CSV file based on a condition in input CSV

Tags: python, csv

I want to write only certain rows from an input CSV file, to an output CSV based on a condition: if the condition is met, write the **Previous row, Current Row and Next Row** to the output CSV. This is what I have done so far:

```
with open('DATA 12-09-19.csv',newline ='') as csvfile:
  bData = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
  header = next(bData)
  data = []  

  for row in bData:
      date = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
      open_price = float(row[1])
      high_price = float(row[2])
      low_price = float(row[3])
      close_price = float(row[4])
      sup = ((high_price - open_price)* 100)
      sown = ((open_price - low_price)* 100)
      data.append([date,open_price,high_price,low_price,close_price,round(sup),round(sown)])

with open("Result_Data.csv",'w',newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output,delimiter=',')
    csv_output.writerow(header)
    for row in data:
        if row[0].time() >= datetime.strptime(starting_time, '%H:%M').time() and row[0].time() <= datetime.strptime(ending_time, '%H:%M').time(): #Condition 1 to be met
            if row[5] >= 7 or row[6] >= 7: #Condition 2 to be met
                csv_output.writerow(row) # Only outputting current row
```

My data columns are:

Date,open,high,low,close,sup,sown.

What should I do to also write the previous and next row to the output CSV instead of only the current as it is now using the csv module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use an index for your row.

```
for i in range(1, len(data)-1):
    if data[i][0].time() >= datetime.strptime(starting_time, '%H:%M').time() and data[i][0].time() <= datetime.strptime(ending_time, '%H:%M').time(): #Condition 1 to be met
        if data[i][5] >= 7 or data[i][6] >= 7: #Condition 2 to be met
            csv_output.writerow(data[i-1])
            csv_output.writerow(data[i]) 
            csv_output.writerow(data[i+1])
```

range between 1 and len(data)-1 because else you will get an index error for the first or last row.

Additional Note: if 2 connected rows (e.g. row 2 and 3) both meet the criteria row 2 and 3 will obviously be written twice. I dont know if that is your intention or the criteria prevents that from happening.

Edit:

```
ids = []
for i in range(1, len(data)-1):
    if data[i][0].time() >= datetime.strptime(starting_time, '%H:%M').time() and data[i][0].time() <= datetime.strptime(ending_time, '%H:%M').time(): #Condition 1 to be met
        if data[i][5] >= 7 or data[i][6] >= 7: #Condition 2 to be met
            if (i-1) not in ids:
                csv_output.writerow(data[i-1])
                ids.append(i-1)
            if i not in ids:
                csv_output.writerow(data[i]) 
                ids.append(i)
            if (i+1) not in ids:
                csv_output.writerow(data[i+1])
                ids.append(i+1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, this is what I needed. I see what you mean now by your additional note, and it IS indeed annoying. How do I prevent duplicate rows?

Comment: on top of my head: You could make a list with row indexes and check if the rows you are going to write are already written. There may be a smarter solution to this tho. Ill make an Edit in a sec